# Add Image For UIBarButtonItem From xib File- Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to add an image for my `UIBarButtonItem` from the `xib` file itself. However, I am getting a grey coloured button which is of the same size and shape as that of my image. How can I display the image correctly and directly from my `xib` file itself without going into the writing of code manually ?? The button is present on a toolbar. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I don't think you can. Not everything in iOS is accesible via editing XIB files. Is there a reason you're refraining from using code?

Comment: I was searching and googling .. I think it would be easier if it is possible to directly add an image from `xib` file itself. I have made a lot of other buttons too in the same toolbar. I think I would have to create another toolbar for the same. So, I am refraining myself to wirte the code to avoid complications.

Comment: I am able to add the image .. but it is not getting displayed with its right colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIButton` beside of `barButtonItem`. It will automatically make a `barButton` and a `Button` inside of that. 
then you need to change `batButtonItem` text to "" and change the `Image` of `UIButton`

as I tested it will work and show your pic beside of `barButtonItem`